# python - domain availability checker not working

Tags: python, validation

I created this function for fun but it doesn't seem to work. I used the `validators` module.
But anyway here's the code.

```py
url = input("Enter the URL: ")
time.sleep(2)
print("Loading URL..")
time.sleep(2)
valid=validators.url(url)
if valid == True:
    print("IS VALID: Yes")
    print("IS ONLINE: Yes")
else:
    print("404 |  URL NOT FOUND_")
```

Once I put a domain, it says it's valid when it isn't. What is causing this/What can I do to fix this small portion of the code? (`you could just give me a website link that solves my question`)

Comment: It's just checking that the syntax of the URL is valid, it's not checking whether the website actually exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your code** actually **check if a string is a valid URL or not**
and doesn't send any HTTP request(that check if a URL really exists or not).

**To ckeck if a URL exists** you can use the **below code**, that **sends an HTTP request** and checks if the status of website **exist(200) or not**.

You have to import the **requests** library.

```
import requests

# Enter URL
# Example of valid URL: http://example.com/
# Example of NON valid URL: example.com/

url = str(input("Enter the URL: "))

try:
    # Try to GET a webpage
    valid = requests.get(url)

    # Check if URL is valid or not
    if valid.status_code == 200:
        print("URL IS VALID = OK")
    else:
        print("URL ISN'T VALID")

except BaseException as ex:
    print("Exception: " + str(ex))
```